# Can we not take column name in dictionary when converting df to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ABC ID
0   4   M01
1   3   M02
2   5   M03
```

When i am using `df.set_index(['ID']).to_dict()` this gives me

```
{'ABC':{'M01':4,'M02':3,'M03':5}}
```

Required output is

```
{'M01':4,'M02':3,'M03':5}
```

Comment: In the future, please do not post dataframe examples with pipes and dashes, but rather post the data as it is, or even as a short code snippet to generate the dataframe. To learn more, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you want to turn the series defined by `df['ABC']` into a `dict`, not the entire DataFrame.
try: `df.set_index(['ID'])['ABC'].to_dict()`, it should result in the required output.

Answer (score 0):

#### `dict` and `zip`

Sometimes for simple tasks like this, it's better to use straight Python and avoid the unnecessary creation of Pandas objects just to get a dictionary.

```
dict(zip(df['ID'], df['ABC']))

{'M01':4,'M02':3,'M03':5}
```